# Get the count of files coming in UNIX folder after certain datestamp

Tags: linux, file, date, unix

I want to get the count of files coming into UNIX directory after certain date stamp.

e.g. I have a folder with the date `28062017` and files are copied to it in certain time.

I want to get the count of file coming from certain time.
say

```
Jun 28 21:17 file 1
Jun 28 21:18 file 2
Jun 28 21:19 file 3
Jun 28 21:20 file 4
Jun 28 21:21 file 5
Jun 28 21:22 file 6
Jun 28 21:23 file 7
Jun 28 21:24 file 8
```

I want to have the count of files generated after `Jun 28 21:21`.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: If you have a reference file say `ref-file` and you wish to find the files newer than the `ref-file` then use `find /path/to/folder/ -type f -type f -anewer ref-file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` using `newermt` (for modification time): `find . -newermt "2017-01-03" -type f -ls | wc -l` and than count the number of lines.

For example:

```
herbert@projects:~/tmp/datetest$ touch -t 201701020100 a.txt
herbert@projects:~/tmp/datetest$ touch -t 201701030100 b.txt
herbert@projects:~/tmp/datetest$ touch -t 201701040100 c.txt
herbert@projects:~/tmp/datetest$ find . -newermt "2017-01-03" -type f -ls
 82353    0 -rw-r--r--   1 herbert  herbert         0 Jan  4 01:00 ./c.txt
 82352    0 -rw-r--r--   1 herbert  herbert         0 Jan  3 01:00 ./b.txt
herbert@projects:~/tmp/datetest$ find . -newermt "2017-01-03" -type f -ls | wc -l
2
```